# Can I use 1x4 boards for raised platform support?

Tags: floor

I'm making small mini golf modules for use at home that will be 24"x24" each and just be placed on the floor next to each other. I wanted to make them as lightweight as I can for a reasonable cost. I'm wondering if its safe to use 1x4 boards for the frame and support boards under the plywood floor.

If not, what if I used 2x4 for the 24x24 frame and then 1x4 boards for the two center support beams?

Just so its clear, I'm expecting to be able to walk on these so each one would need to safely support 200 pounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joined perfectly, 1x4 boards would work. However, you'll get more nailing (/screwing) surface, possibly lower cost, and only slightly greater weight from 2x4s.

You mention center support beams... I'm not really clear on how you plan on putting those in, but you probably don't need them with 2x4s.

I'd suggest at least 1/2" plywood on top.

Comment: You say slightly greater weight, wouldn't the frame part be twice the weight with 2x4s?

Comment: A wet 2x4x8' probably weighs 13#. Dry is much lighter. So yes, double, but double a small number is still a relatively small number.

Comment: Actually where I live a 1x4x8 is 20 cents less and half the weight (4.7# vs. 9.0#) of a 2x4 pre-cut stud.  But I can see your point about 1x4s being hard to work with.